# Catalyst::Controller::REST returns 415 unsupported media type

Tags: perl, rest, catalyst

I want to write restful api via Catalyst, and use for this [Catalyst::Controller::REST][1].

I have written that code.

```
package addressbook::Controller::REST;
use strict;
use warnings;
use base qw(Catalyst::Controller::REST);


sub user :Local :ActionCLass('REST') :Args(1){
    my( $self, $c, $id ) = @_;

    $c->stash( id => $id );

}

# Get user
sub user_GET {
    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;

    my $user = $c->model('DB::User')->find( { id => $c->stash->{id} } );

    if ( $user ){
            $self->status_ok($c, entity => { firstname => $user->firstname } ); 
    }
    else {
            $self->status_not_found($c, message => 'No matching user'); 
    }
}

__PACKAGE__->config(default => 'text/x-json');
1;
```

Then i run the server, go to localhost:3000/rest/user/1 (i have user by that id) and get

> Cannot find a Content-Type supported by your client.

I try to set **PACKAGE**->config application/json, text/xml, text/html, text/x-yaml ... but it's not help.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As implemented, Catalyst Action REST does content negotiation on the request to determine the serialization method to be used. The default setting is only a fallback and normally your request in the real world will contain a content type.

Documentation on the supported content types and how to map in new deserializers can be found here:
[enter link description here](http://search.cpan.org/~frew/Catalyst-Action-REST-1.14/lib/Catalyst/Controller/REST.pm). Note also that recent versions remove built in support for YAML
which would have been the default response to text/html if you just requested the url in your browser.

Use curl or test from a real browser using Javascript

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:3000/rest/user/1
```

Also check your installed version of Catalyst which will appear on the info line as you start up the server.

Comment: Thanks. I rummaged in detail in the documentation and solved the problem